# IE Automation - Excel VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to do IE Automation through Excel VBA code.

I have a web page which has Top, Middle and results forms. I need to input values in the Middle form but unable to get any controls from this and get it as 0. Ie.Document.forms.Length gives 0. Tried the below code as well but does not work.

```
Ie.Document.forms("SearchForm").elements("PolicyNumber").Value = "Josh"
```

Looks like this form is on a frame but don't see frame reference inthe HTML code. HTML code is as below:

```
<body bgcolor="white"> 
    <form method=POST name="SearchForm" action="PolicySearch" target="resultframe" > 
        <input type=hidden name="NewSearch" value="True" ></input> 
        <table class=box2 cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="760" align="top" halign="left"> 
            <tr> 
            <td class="name" align="left">
                Policy# :<input type=text name="PolicyNumber" maxlength="10" value="" size="10"></input>
            </td>
```

Comment: <body bgcolor="white">
  <form method=POST name="SearchForm" action="PolicySearch" target="resultframe" >
<input type=hidden name="NewSearch" value="True" ></input>
<table class=box2 cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="0"  width="760" align="top" halign="left">
  <tr>
  <td class="name" align="left">Policy# :<input type=text name="PolicyNumber" maxlength="10" value="" size="10"></input></td>

Comment: Can anyone please help me how to post my answer specifying my code sothat you all can see it? I am a new comer to this website and need advice pls.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: What is the right website. I am viewing http://stackoverflow.com but it does not have any tool bar and nothing on this website is show in format. May be I am viewing wrong web site. Can anyone help pls? I badly need help on my question

Comment: Have you checked that the forms are not in frames?

Answer (score 0):

try thing as

`Ie.Document.getElementsByName("PolicyNumber").Item(0).Value="Josh"`

or

`Iie.Document.getElementsByName("PolicyNumber").Value="Josh"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

declare a new variable:

`Dim Elements As IHTMLElementCollection`

Set the elements with the form and tag name, eg. input

`Set Elements = IE.Document.forms("SearchForm").Document.getElementsByTagName("input")`

Pass the value to the text / input

`Elements("PolicyNumber").Value = "Josh"`

**Note:** the code above is originally for *frames* and need to add  **MS HTML Objects library**  in the references. Though you can use Elements by declaring as object, declaring as IHTMLElementCollection will have events when you press "."